# Replacing binary references with NuGet References for hundreds of projects

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, nuget

Consider a large existing codebase with approx. 150+ solutions and 800+ C# projects. Many are unit tests written using NUnit. All those projects references "nunit.framework.dll" from a "lib" folder that is checked in. There is also a number of 3rd party assemblies in the "lib" folder which has corresponding NuGet packages.

I could manually open 150+ solutions and migrate each reference to to NuGet. However this is proving to be tedious and error prone. I wrote a C# console application to parse csproj files and identify which packages needs to be installed for the respective project. So I know that 300+ projects requires the NUnit package to be installed.

How to I programmatically automate the installation of a package in a solution, matching the exact same behavior as doing so manually within Visual Studio 2013? I looked everywhere, and only found an [extension](https://github.com/BenPhegan/NuGet.Extensions) however, it doesn't perform a full install with dependencies etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NuGet: automatically migrate references to packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557052/nuget-automatically-migrate-references-to-packages)

Comment: @bloudraak I'm about to embark on a similar task - is your console app code posted anywhere?

Answer (score 3):

Create a `packages.config` file with just an entry for the NUnit packages
`package.config` should look something like this check for correct package name, version and target info

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="nunit.framework" version="2.6.3" targetFramework="net45" requireReinstallation="true" />
</packages>
```

extend the utility you wrote to parse `.csproj` files
 to edit the csproj file as well and add the below tags

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="packages.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

packages.config should be copied to all project folders; else if your projects are going to have the same reference you can choose to Add the packages.config as a link

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="$(SolutionDir)packages.config">
       <Link>$(SolutionDir)packages.config</Link>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Once this is done open the solution in visual studio and go to the NuGet console and enter the below
command; NuGet will resolve missing dependencies and add them.

```
update-package
```

Comment: Am I correct at assuming that the command line `nuget update <solution>` will do the trick once I updated all the projects in a solution?

Comment: My assumption doesn't work. The project files are not modified since the packages that were restored are already up to date.

Comment: The suggested process doesn't seem to work that well. Calling `Update-Package` doesn't change the binary reference to a NuGet reference and if you don't specify a package id will upgrade existing packages to incompatible versions.  When using `Update-Package -Reinstall -Safe` then, on occasion, packages will be removed and the project doesn't compile. On other occasions the process will fail with COM errors. This process also takes a long time for large solutions; up to two hours for some of my solutions (which more than often failed or produced incorrect results.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following snippet:

```
Get-Project -All | foreach-object {IF (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String 'Reference Include="XXX"') {Install-Package XXX -ProjectName $_.FullName}}
```

Replace `XXX` with your desired package name and run the snippet in `Tools->NuGet Package Manager->Package Manager Console` from within Visual Studio.

Comment: At first I tried out of the box but then I realized that 'Reference Include="XXX"' is the content of csproj file. In my case that was fortunately the same all over the place ..\ProjName\ProjName and you need \\ instead of one \
It is easy to find what is written in each csproj about this reference if they are not referenced within the same structure. It would be still a couple of calls. And yes it is working. Happy me.